# ¿Cómo realizar una lista desplegable dependiente en VBA con Excel?

Tags: excel, vba

tengo un problema con visualizar una lista despegable dependiente en VBA con Excel para ingresar registros, esta es mi hoja de cálculo llamada DATOS con la tabla, primero tengo un problema con los espacios vacíos que en la lista desplegable me aparecen y no sé cómo quitarlos.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta es la fórmula que utilizo en la casilla “B19”: =DESREF(INDIRECTO(DIRECCION(1;COINCIDIR(B15;A1:D1;0)));1;0;11;1)
 Esta fórmula la coloque en administrador de nombres con el nombre de: listanombres
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El otro problema que tengo es que al hacer este proceso con VBA, me aparece la primera lista, pero al seleccionar un valor me da error.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi código es el siguiente en VBA

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("DATOS").Range("B15").Value = Me.ComboBox1.Value
Me.ComboBox2.Value = ""
Me.ComboBox2.RowSource = "listanombres"
End Sub
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("DATOS").Range("B15").ClearContents
ComboBox1.List = Worksheets("DATOS").Range("A2:A4").Value
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

El codigo que me funciono para quitar el error enunciado fue:

```
Dim hprod As Worksheet
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
ComboBox3.List = Worksheets("DATOS").Range("A8:A9").Value
Dim nCol As Integer
Set hprod = Worksheets("DATOS")
nCol = hprod.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
For i = 2 To nCol
 ComboBox1.AddItem hprod.Cells(1, i).Value
Next i
End Sub
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
Dim IndiceCat As Integer
Dim ufila As Integer
IndiceCat = ComboBox1.ListIndex + 2
ufila = hprod.Cells(Rows.Count, IndiceCat).End(xlUp).Row
ComboBox2.Clear
For j = 2 To ufila
 ComboBox2.AddItem hprod.Cells(j, IndiceCat).Value
Next j
End Sub
```

Si hay alguna sugerencia para acortar el codigo lo agradeceria.